# error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003. Unable to request services on iOS app: process can’t be completed - Ionic

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m developing an app with the ionic framework v3. My app uses Firebase and Geofire plugins to locate some points on a Google map.
App works fine for Android devices and Browsers but for iOS, nothing happens.

When I request the database - directly to Firebase or using Geofire - I get the following errors on Xcode console.

```
[] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003
[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1.1:2][0x7fcb577056f0] get output frames failed, state 8196
```

I did some research about the ***NSURLErrorDomain*** error but I found nothing for the ***-1003*** flag.
I don’t know what can produce this error.

Any idea?

Comment: hi paul, any luck with this?

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is with the emulator. I ran the app on a real device and it worked. But I have no idea to solve this issue on the emulator.

Comment: Thank you Paul! I actually have this one when running on the device. But I am refactoring a lot a the moment, hopefully I will not to have to deal with it.